# Image not displaying on ImageMagick/PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

There's a tutorial that I've tried using ImageMagick and tried to alter some of it.

```
<?php
$inFile = "/home/trainee/Desktop/image.jpg";
$outFile = "/home/trainee/Desktop/test-cropped.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($inFile);
$image->cropImage(400,400, 30,10);
$image->writeImage($outFile);
?>
```

Expected output:
[image displayed]

Actual output:
None,null

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Imagick::writeImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimage.php) will write the image to disk, and return a true on success. If you would like to send the image data to the output buffer (like a web-browser), simply read the generated file

```php
<?php
$inFile = "/home/trainee/Desktop/image.jpg";
$outFile = "/home/trainee/Desktop/test-cropped.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($inFile);
$image->cropImage(400,400, 30,10);
if ( $image->writeImage($outFile) )
{
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  readfile( $outFile );
}
?>
```

You can also take advantage of [Imagick::__toString](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/imagick_class.c#L2949), and skip writing the image to disk.

```
<?php
$inFile = "/home/trainee/Desktop/image.jpg";
$outFile = "/home/trainee/Desktop/test-cropped.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($inFile);
$image->cropImage(400,400, 30,10);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $image;
?>
```